# What's wrong with my plot of a 3D seashell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

My task is to draw such seashell in Matlab.

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

My code is

```
s = linspace(0,2*pi);
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
[s, t] = meshgrid(s, t); 
n=2;
a=15;
b=500;
c=10;
X =a.*(1-(t./(2*pi))).*cos(n.*t).*(1+cos(s))+c.*cos(n.*t);
Y =a.*(1-(t./(2*pi))).*sin(n.*t).*(1+cos(s))+c.*sin(n.*t);
Z = b.*(t./(2*pi))+a.*(1-(t./2*pi)).*sin(s);
surf(X,Y,Z ,'LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong','EdgeColor','none')
colormap(jet)
camlight right
```

and this is what that code produces:

[image]

I don't understand what the problem is. Why doesn't it look right?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Maybe the formula is wrong (z-values look odd...)  or the parameters don't match. Where do you have it from? One thing: add `axis equal vis3d` in the end so the z-axis won't get squeezed.

Comment: You missed a pair of parentheses in `Z` for `2*pi`. Unsure if this will solve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line here:`Z = b.*(t./(2*pi))+a.*(1-(t./2*pi)).*sin(s);`has an algebraical mistake.
It should be:  `Z = b*(t/(2*pi))+a*(1-(t/(2*pi))).*sin(s);` With yours parametrization I got this result: [image]

And using different parametrization found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seashell.html) I got something like: 
[image] and with your parameters same code:[image] 
Also use operators like `./` and `.*` when you divide and multiply arrays element-vise and there is no need to do it for scalar-array multiplication/division.

Comment: Exactly. Also just found out that this was the problem. Changing `b` to `50` will yield the supposed result.